# Dash in regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

According to the documentation, [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) must return all matches of a regular expression in a string. However,

```
"Foo 09:00 bar 21-00 foobar".match(/\d{2}[:\-]\d{2}/)
```

returns only `["09:00"]`, whereas the expected result is `["09:00", "21:00"]`. Why?

By the way,

```
"Foo 09:00 bar 21-00 foobar".split(/\d{2}[:\-]\d{2}/)
```

returns `["Foo ", " bar ", " foobar"]`, which means `21-00` is matched by the regular expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing `g` (global) modifier. Use it.

If you don't, it will stop at the first match.

Like this:

```
"Foo 09:00 bar 21-00 foobar".match(/\d{2}[:-]\d{2}/g)
```

Also, you don't need to escape `-` if it is at the starting or at the end of character class.

The [MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) which you referred also says:

> 1. returns the same result as RegExp.exec(str) [i.e. the captured groups, index, etc] if the regular expression does not include the `g`
>      flag
> 2. returns an Array containing all matches if the regular expression includes the g flag

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation, [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

> - returns the same result as `RegExp.exec(str)` [i.e. the captured groups, index, etc] if the regular expression does not include the `g` flag
> - returns an Array containing all matches if the regular expression includes the `g` flag

```
> "Foo 09:00 bar 21-00 foobar".match(/\d{2}[:\-]\d{2}/)
Array ["09:00", index:4, input:"Foo 09:00 bar 21-00 foobar"]
> "Foo 09:00 bar 21-00 foobar".match(/\d{2}[:\-]\d{2}/g)
Array ["09:00", "21-00"]
```